# Distance / Metric between two regression models?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, distance, metric

I wonder if there is any theory or work about the "similarity" of two regression models. For example, if it is linear regression, the "similarity" could be defined by the l-2 distance between the coefficients vectors of the two models. Let's assume they are in the same hypothesis space (parameter space) and is fitted with the same dataset.

Comment: Are both models fitted using the same dataset?

Comment: At least if the parameter space is the same you could use the Le Cam distance, see https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01314223/document for an accessible introduction.

Comment: Yes there are fitted using the same dataset and is in the same hypothesis space.

Comment: Of course one can construct mathematical definitions like this--but to what end?  What would your objective be?  Until we know that, it's hard to see that there's any statistical question here.